# Navbar items alingment for bootstrap 5

Tags: html, navbar

I am sticking to this problem for such a long time. Please help me to fix it... I really tried various ways but none of them is actually working.
I want my login button at the end of my navbar(right side) and when I decrease the screen size i wanted it to be appear on the left side of the burgger menu
Here is my code -

```
<header class="header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="image/logo.png" alt="" width="150px" height="35px">
            </a>

            <div class="login-nav ms-auto mb-2 me-2 ">
                <ul class="navbar-nav login">
                    <li class="navbar-item login-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

</header>
```

I want them like these pictures :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQj5b.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vehyn.png)

Comment: you need a bit custom css for that

Comment: can u help me please

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround. There are two login links.

```
<header class="header">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    
            <div class="container-fluid">
    
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="image/logo.png" alt="" width="150px" height="35px">
                </a>
                <div class="mb-2 me-2 d-block d-md-none">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav login">
                        <li class="navbar-item login-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 ">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-2 me-2 d-none d-md-block">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav login">
                        <li class="navbar-item login-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    
    </header>
```

Comment: But now hamburger menu is appearing in the middle

Comment: Edited. Check now. It'll change on `display md (medium)`

Answer (score 0):

```
<header class="header">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">

        <div class="container-fluid">

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="image/logo.png" alt="" width="150px" height="35px">
            </a>

            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-2 d-block d-md-none">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">

                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 ">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto me-2 d-none d-md-block">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    <li class="nav-item ">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Login</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>


        </div>
    </nav>

</header>
```

This is working as expected :) This for the idea Yasin

Comment: Welcome. You can mark that as acepted answer

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.